# SQL statement to get individual values from multiple rows from right table as columns in output

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables:

Table A:

```
ID  
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table B:

```
ID  UDFNumber UDFValue
1   5         ID1sUDF5Value
1   6         ID1sUDF6Value
1   7         ID1sUDF7Value
1   8         ID1sUDF8Value
1   9         ID1sUDF9Value
2   5         ID2sUDF5Value
2   6         ID2sUDF6Value
2   7         ID2sUDF7Value
2   8         ID2sUDF8Value
2   9         ID2sUDF9Value
etc
```

I am trying to output the values of only UDF5 and UDF9 as columns for each row in table A.

Output I am looking for:

```
ID  UDF5            UDF9
1   ID1sUDF5Value   ID1sUDF9Value
2   ID2sUDF5Value   ID2sUDF9Value
3   ID3sUDF5Value   ID3sUDF9Value
```

etc.

What join/sql statement would produce that result? MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, 
    max(case when udfnumber = 5 then udfvalue end) as udf5,
    max(case when udfnumber = 9 then udfvalue end) as udf9
from tableb
where udfnumber in (5, 9)
group by id
```

Note that you don't need `tablea` to generate the result that you want - unless you want to allow rows without a match in `tableb`. If so:

```
select a.id, 
    max(case when b.udfnumber = 5 then b.udfvalue end) as udf5,
    max(case when b.udfnumber = 9 then b.udfvalue end) as udf9
from tablea a
left join tableb b on b.id = a.id and b.udfnumber in (5, 9)
group by a.id
```

Finally: for just two values, joining twice is a viable alternative:

```
select a.id, b5.udfvalue as udf5, b9.udfvalue as udf9
from tablea a
left join tableb b5 on b5.id = a.id and b5.udfnumber = 5
left join tableb b9 on b9.id = a.id and b8.udfnumber = 9
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I will be using the additional example with the join as this is part of a larger solution the join is required for. I just couldn't work out how to get the two rows from table B as a joinable row to table A with the values as columns. Thank you.